# Как применить метод filter в шаблоне

Tags: python, django

```
1.for profile in profils:
2.>>friends = profile.friend.all()
    print('user list: ',profile.name, "друзей: ",friends.count())
3.>>if friends.filter(user2=profil):
        print("вы друзья")
```

- 1-Выводит объекты пользователей у каждого из которых есть друзья
- 2-Сортирует объекты профилей на количество друзей
- 3-Проверяет есть ли объект пользователя А в списке друзей пользователя B

> Через консоль проходит проверка статуса друзей а в шаблоне .html я не могу применить фильтр .filter(user2=profil) я пробовал сделать так

```
{% for users in user_list %}
<h3>{{ users.friend.all().filter|user2:profil }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

но мне выдаёт ошибку Filter подскажите как мне быть

**Вывод из консоли**

вы авторизованы как:  A

---

user list:  A друзей:  2

---

user list:  B друзей:  1
вы друзья

---

user list:  C друзей:  1
вы друзья

---

user list:  D друзей:  0

---